# ngAfterViewInit() is not woking as it suppose to work In Angular 15

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

[image: Image for clarification]

I am Using Material UI Library and Angular 15,
I am trying to initialize the color and size, and quantity fields, But it is not working here is my code
for the color

```
<div class="d-inline-flex"   #input id="bdiv"
*ngFor="let item of productColor; let x = index" (change)="sizeAvaliable(color,x)">
<input #input class="form-check-input  d-none" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions"  
id="inlineRadio{{x+1}}" value={{item.colorID}} [(ngModel)]="color"  >
<label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio{{x+1}}">
<img   class="rounded-circle pic" src="/assets/Swatch/{{item.colorValue}}.jpg"
  alt="{{item.colorValue}}"
  style="height: 2.375rem;width: 2.375rem; padding: 1px;" id="pic{{x}}" >
</label>
</div>
```

This is the data of productColor that comes from an API

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {colorID: 1, colorValue: 'Black'}
1: {colorID: 2, colorValue: 'Navy'}
```

color is Propery in ts  public color = 1;

When the user chooses the color I call a function to load the available sizes with its quantities

```
sizeAvaliable(productID:number ,colorID:number, x:number){
  //to add the golden boarder
  document.querySelectorAll(".pic").forEach(pic=> pic.classList.remove('picked'))
  document.getElementById(`pic${x}`)?.classList.add('picked')

  //reset quanity 
  this.quantity = 1;
  this.productEntryService.getAvaliableSizes(productID, colorID).subscribe(p => {
    //Displaying the name of selected color
    this.colorName = p[0].color.colorValue
    //Showing the avalaible sizes of that product with that color
    p.sort((a,b)=> a.sizeID-b.sizeID)
    this.productSizes = p
    this.size = p[0].sizeID
 })
 this.qty=1;
}
```

So I am even trying to initialize the size and quantity fields but with no use
I tried  ngAfterViewInit() with set timeout  to select the first element of color
but I don't want to use set timeout without it returned Undefined (it is not rendered yet)
here is the code

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
window.setTimeout(()=>document.getElementById('inlineRadio1')?.click(),1000 )
}
```

another way is to use ngAfterViewChecked() lifetime hook When I log the element It returned Undifiened for the first 4 logs
and after that, it log the element
But I don't want to use it as it triggers after any change happen

Comment: It depends on when your `getAvaliableSizes` resolved. Why dont you select after you receive the response. You should refactor this code. You should not interact with the dom in that way (`document.[...]`)

Comment: I used also view child , and it didn't work either  
how should I interact with the DOM then.